# Debugging production javascript errors

Tags: javascript, django, heroku, logging, console.log

How can I make console.log visible to my django site deployed on heroku?

I  made a wordlegolf site, [www.wordlegolfing.com](http://www.wordlegolfing.com), where my friends and I play wordle and it tracks our scores daily. I made it in Django and have it deployed on Heroku. I am getting errors randomly and having issues recreating them and fixing them. I added a logger to my Python code but it's not really telling me much as the javascript seems to be the issue.
Can I add a logger to my javascript code that I can read from Papertrail or another log management tool?
Also, the only thing I could think of my errors being is from poor internet connections, is that possible?

I can not debug this from a local host using console.log because I can't recreate the errors.
I tried django-js-logger (https://github.com/snok/django-js-logger) and I seem to get it somewhat working as it does a post request every time console.log is called but Im not sure how to show any data

[20/May/2023 08:50:39] "POST /js-logs/ HTTP/1.1" 204 0

[20/May/2023 08:50:39] "POST /js-logs/ HTTP/1.1" 204 0

I also thought about using an ajax call to send the logs to python which I think is the same concept as the django-js-logger but Im not sure if that will slow down my program too much and cause issues